# PHP - how can i use value from cookie to redirct to profile page

Tags: php, html

I'm making a website that has a simple profile system.

All my profiles have a separate `.php` file with their id in a name like `1.php`, `2.php` and so on.

On index navigation bar, I have the option to go to persons own profile (my page requires login on every page so it will work fine).

That's is where my problem is. I need to take id from my cookies (1 for example) and use it to go to `profile/1.php`.

Since my navigation bar is made with HTML, I need to use `href` system to redirect, but `href` cant recognize code from PHP `$id`.

I tried to make separated redirect file but that gave me `Cannot modify header information` error.

Is there a way for me to make such mess work (just learning) or do I need to scrap that idea?

Comment: Saving values to the session variable is what you are looking for.  For example: $_SESSION['profile_number'] = 1.  This should be done when the user logs into the system.

Comment: why do you need separate files for each profile?

Comment: @BrandonDixon what does it do better than cookie can't do?

Comment: @prakashtank I feel like it's a lot better to learn and tinker around when I can see everything for everyone. I see why it would be just a shit coding, but im just learning and not publishing it anywhere

Comment: Whenever the page is accessed by a user, the browser sends the cookie's session ID to your PHP page.  The appropriate $_SESSION vars are accessed based on this session ID.  In this sense, you're using the cookie to save the info, but the info isn't saved directly in the cookie.

Comment: Also, I did not realize until now, PHP can actually directly access the cookie, it seems:

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but href cant recognize code from PHP ($id).

You just start the PHP tag inside the href like so

```
<a href="profile/<?= $id ?>.php">My profile</a>
```

Comment: What does the url look like when you view the source code? Maybe you dont have an `$id` variable defined.

Comment: tried it on my other page, it works. but doesn't seem to work on my main page